# Testng files syncing back to previous versionissue after maven goal in intellij

Tags: xml, maven, intellij-idea, testng

I'm running a framework with maven goal to run a specific testng xml suite file.

(Testng files are located under target - test-classes -testng - smoketest.xml)

e.g. smoketest.xml

mvn clean test -DsuitXMLFile= smoketest.xml

Issue is if I create a new scenarios.xml file under testng folder. It will be deleted after I run the mvn goal.

If I edit the existing testng file (e.g. adding another scenario to smoketest.xml), then If I run the mvn goal (mvn clean test -DsuitXMLFile= smoketest.xml), the new changes witll be ignored and deleted after the the mvn goal is executed. I notice a message as ""syncing.." being displayed at top corner of the xml file while this happens.

How can I resolve this issue? I want to make changes as I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

`/target` folder is a folder for storing generated and compiled data, some results files etc.
So you don't need to use it for files/folders creation, because as long as you do `clean` command from terminal - Maven cleans out all the content inside of `/target` folder.
So you need to store your file in another place.